# Watson Studio change multiple column types at the same type in Refine

Tags: watson-studio

I am loading a file to watson studio with 152 columns and I have the problem that by default it takes the `string` type.
Is there any way to change several columns at the same time?
I know I can do it column by column but 150 columns are too much.

I tried `"mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(as.double(.x)),.x,as.double(.x)))"`

It works in the preview but fails when I launch the flow with the following error:

```
19 Feb 2019-20:15:25+0100: Job execution started
 19 Feb 2019-20:15:32+0100: Error in ifelse(is.na(as.double(.x)), .x, as.double(.x)): object 'COLUMN1' not found
 19 Feb 2019-20:15:32+0100: Job execution ended
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do for all the string columns, please use `mutate_if` instead of mutate_all()

```
mutate_if(is.character,as.double)
```

It should change all the string types to double.

So if you want to not convert any specific column you would have to do something like this, -matches() would list all columns other than specified column and would apply double conversion to only those columns.

```
mutate_at(vars(-matches("columnname")),funs(as.double(.)))
```

Comment: This works, but the first column is the target column and it is really a string, so when I aply this solution it goes to NA. Any sugestion, thanks?

Comment: updated the answer with mutate_at(vars(-matches("columnname")),funs(as.double(.)))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.